# make ajax request before form gets submitted, and submit data after ajax is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a form with submit button on my page. When user clicks on the button, I would like  to make an ajax request, and if that request returns the right result, proceed with submitting the form.

However this is a bit tricky, since the form gets submitted before the ajax gets response, nor does it care what the response was. How do you create such functionality?

I tried setting the submit button as disabled, but than the click event does not get registered at all.

```
$(".submit-button").click(function() {
    $.post( "exists.php",{ email: email}, function( data ) {
        if (data=="wrong result") {
            // display error the the user
        } else {
            //proceed with submitting form
        }
    });
}


<form action="register" method="post">
   <fieldset class="c-fieldset">
       <label class="input-data"> Email: <input type="email" name="email-address" required > </label>
   </fieldset>
   <input type="submit" class="submit-button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent submitting automaticly , check and if result succed use the  form `.submit()` function. (i've added an id to the form )

```js
$(".submit-button").on("click", function(e) {

      e.preventDefault(); // prevent submitting form here
      var email = $("[name='email-address']").val();
      $.post("exists.php", {
          email: email
        }, function(data) {
          if (data == "wrong result") {
            // display error the the user
          } else {
            //proceed with submitting form
             $("#myForm").submit();
      
          }
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="register" method="post" id="myForm">
  <fieldset class="c-fieldset">
    <label class="input-data"> Email: <input type="email" name="email-address" required > </label>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" class="submit-button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `$("#myForm").submit();` - won't that just call the `$("#myForm").on("submit"` again? or is jQuery smart enough to determine the difference?

Comment: It appears it is smart enough

Answer (score 1):

You can `submit` the form in else block

```
$(".submit-button").click(function(e) {
// prevent the default behavior of the form
e.preventDefault();
      $.post("exists.php", {
          email: email
        }, function(data) {
          if (data == "wrong result") {
            // display error the the user
          }
        } else {
          $("#myForm").submit();
        }
      }
    }

<form action="register" method="post" id = 'myForm'>
  // Added id to form
  // rest of the code
</form>
```